# Use Array in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array and I just want to use it in my table.
This is my idea but i don't know how to use the array to be shown inside a td-tag:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function list() {
        var list = ['Tim','Tom','Tam']
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Place 1: list[0]</td>
            <td>Place 2: list[1]</td>
            <td>Place 3: lsit[2]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The hole idea is to generate an array from a Python Script, which gets it from a xlsx file, and give it over to a HTML page.

Comment: First ditch the function, then `<script>document.write(list[0])</script>` will work. There are countless better ways of doing it though.

Comment: Sorry, but in my opinion this question is too vague. You should probably learn more about JavaScript and ask a more specific question later on.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array, and for each element create an TD element.

```js
var list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    pushTo = arr => {
    arr.forEach((cur , i) => {
    let tempElem = document.createElement("TD");
        tempElem.innerHTML = `list[${i}]`;
        tlist.appendChild(tempElem);
    });
    };
    
    pushTo(list);
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="tlist">
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var list = ['Tim', 'Tom', 'Tam'];
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <script>
       var tr = document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr')[0];
        
        for (var l in list) {
         var index = parseInt(l) + 1;
            
         var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = 'Place ' + index + ': ' + list[l];
            
         tr.appendChild(td);
        }
      </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

AngularJS:

```js
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);

angularApp.controller('angularCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = ['Tim', 'Tom', 'Tam'];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="angularCtrl"> 
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="l in list">Pace {{$index + 1}}: {{l}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```